# Interior points in topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X= \mathbb{R^2}$ with subway metric. Here subway metric is the [Paris metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_metric#Paris_metric). Let $A= [-1,1] \times \{0\}$. What is the interior point of $A$? I would say it is $(-1,1) \times \{0\}$ but I got it wrong. Can someone help?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the definition of Paris Metric (@RutherfordMark Please read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question); for future reference you should either include an explicit definition or provide a link where the definition is given.) And I also cleared the comments discussing what is meant.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thank you for your help! I will keep in mind in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $(0,0)$ is not an interior point of $A$, since the neighbourhoods of the origin in the Paris metric are exactly the neighbourhoods of the origin in the Euclidean metric. The other points in $A$ behave as you thought, so the interior of $A$ is

$$(-1,0)\times\{0\} \cup (0,1)\times\{0\}.$$

Comment: So, the open neighborhood of $(0,0)$ will contain the the origin itself which obviously contains $(0,0)$ and is still  a subset of $A$. So, shouldn't that also be an interior point?

Comment: But a neighbourhood of the origin contains an entire disk whose centre is the origin, so no neighbourhood of the origin is contained in $A$, since all points in $A$ have zero second coordinate.

Comment: @StefanSmith: I realized that my question had created great great confusion. Since I am self studying topology and came across "subway metric" terminology, I assumed that it was standard which was my fault. I apologize to everyone who tried helping me but couldn't due to my mistake.

Comment: @RutherfordMark : Thank you for not taking offense.